# Issue with Global Variables in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use an API but I can only call this once but I need to use this in multiple functions.

I have tried to call it and set it as a global variable and then reference it in the others.

If I do this:

```
$GLOBALS['stateloc'] = 'My State';
```

When I call this in the next function it works correctly and shows "My State".

However when I use

```
$GLOBALS['stateloc'] = $state;
```

It shows up as NULL. If I var_dump $state I get:

```
string(7) "England"
```

So I know the `$state` variable is set.

I just can't figure out how to get the global variable to work based on my variable.

Comment: The question here is: why do you want to use global variables?

Comment: I can only call this API once... I can add it as a function but each time it will call the API when the function is referenced.

Comment: I think you are assigning variable to the global variable when it is empty

Comment: You need to add some real code here and explain it better, as it is now, it's confusing.

Comment: `$GLOBALS` stores _references_ to variables. If the value of `$state` changes after you assigned `$GLOBALS['stateloc'] = $state;`, then accessing `$GLOBALS['stateloc']` will reflect that change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

In main file write: `global $stateloc;`

Then on every beggining of file when you want use `$stateloc` write 
`global $stateloc;`

And use `$stateloc`

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php